# How to clear the value of a kendo Combo Box

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm fairly new to kendo.I have a requirement to load child combo box data from parent combo box also while I change values  it sholud clear the value of existing with child combo and fill with a relevant value.

if someone can  guide me to achieve this that would be great.

Thanks

Chinthaka

Comment: Please look at this demo of cascading comboboxes and tell me, if this what you want, or do you wanna clear parent combobox value when you change you child combobox: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/cascadingcombobox.html

Comment: Hi j4r0 my scenario is based on multiple cascading. Cmb1 Cmb2 Cmb3 So Based on Cmb 1 Cmb2 I need to populate Cmb 3 is this possible with kendo cascading Cheers

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set the value to the new value

```
 $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox").value("Oranges");
```

Or clear it

```
 $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox").value("");
```

Comment: This is a solution, however the big problem with the combo box is that there is no 'X' option that clears the selection built into the control.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

`$("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox").select(-1);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. –

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cascade event of the ComboBox - http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox#events-cascade, along with the value() method, to achieve the functionality that you are looking for